# Typo3 V8: uninstall extensions manually

Tags: typo3-8.x

My Backend shows an error due to an incompatible extension. How can I uninstall it manually? In Typo3 V7 I could edit PackageStates.php like this:

```
    'myownext' => [
        'packagePath' => 'typo3conf/ext/myownext/',
        'state' => 'inactive',
    ],
```

But V8 removed all state keys - and it does not listen to this key if I add it manually. When I remove the whole entry from the file it is added again after refresh of the BE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TYPO3 8.7.19: If I remove an entry of an extension in PackageStates.php the extension is disabled. As example I disable powermail by removing the following entry:

```
'powermail' => [
    'packagePath' => 'typo3conf/ext/powermail/',
],
```

Don't forget to load the file PackageStates.php after editing again on the server-

Comment: Maybe it's an issue of the version I am using: Typo3 V8.1. What do you mean by don't forget... how can I load the file again?

Comment: You should really update to TYPO3 8.7.19. With my little hint I just wanted to remind you that sometimes you change and save a file locally but then miss to transfer it back to the server.

Comment: I mark the question as solved because your answer is correct for recent versions of V8.x